# Haxm installed but it shows install haxm required

Tags: android

in my sdk manager haxm IS installed

[image: check this image]

but

[image: it shows this error]

how can i handle this error?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio, from that dialog it doesn't seem like there's a solution

Comment: tried but not works :(

Comment: You need to enable **vt(virtual technology)** option from BIOS.

Comment: it works well before update emulator. after update emulator not works

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue few days ago,  Here's how i fixed it:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Remove/UnInstall HaxM
3. Run AndroidStudio  as Admin
4. Re-Install HaxM

Thats it.

Comment: my project have gmail login integrations. if i uninstall android studio it might affect sha1 key related problems

Comment: Read again!!, I said **UnInstall Haxm**, didn't said anything about uninstalling AndroidStudio